# Submit is not working after adding oninput to input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Before adding `oninput` in input tag submit button was working fine but after adding it and `function box1(),box2(),box()` of `JavaScript`, it is not working. I used the `java` at back-end and Bootstrap with `HTML` at front-end. I already included all the bootstrap url at bottom with `CSS`, `JavaScript`, `jquery`. I want to call `JavaScript` function after user input its complete input value that's why i used the `oninput` inside `input` tag. What is the solution.

```html
<form action="Emicalculator" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-12 ">
        <div class="jumbotron">

          <h1 class="text-center">EMI Calculator</h1>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" class="nav-collapse">Home Loan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary collapse.in" class="nav-collapse">Personal Loan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary collapse.in" class="nav-collapse">Car Loan</button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" id="home" for="Loan Amount">Home Loan Amount </label>
            <input type="number" name="loanamount" min="0" max="20000000" maxlength="8" oninput="box1()" id="input1" class="form-control" class="home1" placeholder="Enter loan amount" required>
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">min=0, max=200L</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Interest Rate">Interest Rate </label>
            <input type="number" name="interest_rate" min="5" max="20" maxlength="2" oninput="box2()" id="input2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Interest Rate" required>
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">min=5, max=20</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Loan Tenure">Loan Tenure </label>
            <input type="number" name="loan_tenure" min="0" max="30" maxlength="2" oninput="box3()" id="input3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Loan Tenure" required>
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">min=0, max=30</small>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Submit</button>
        <br>

        <script>
          function box1() {

            var check = parseInt((document.getElementById('input1').value));

            if ((check < 0) || (check > 20000000)) {
              alert("Please enter in range between 0 to 20000000");
            }

          }

          function box2() {

            var check = parseInt((document.getElementById('input2').value));

            if ((check < 5) || (check > 20)) {
              alert("Please enter in range between 5 to 20");
            }

          }

          function box3() {

            var check = parseInt((document.getElementById('input3').value));

            if ((check < 0) || (check > 30)) {
              alert("Please enter in range between 0 to 30");
            }

          }
        </script>
```

Comment: What's "not working"? Everything seems fine to me.

Comment: you should close the form first then add your script

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot the `</form>` closing tag

Comment: No. Its there at end. I forgot to add it on above code